# interviewer effect - threshold for intracluster correlation

Tags: survey, reliability

I want to estimate interviewer effects on certain questions in a survey. Each respondent was interviewed once by one of four interviewers and the answers to some questions vary greatly by interviewer. I'm having difficulty working out the best way to report this though. 
I've calculated the intracluster correlation coefficient (rho). I read somewhere that an ICC range of 0.0-0.07 is acceptable / to be expected and that >0.07 indicates interviewer effects. I only read it once though, which I find suspicious - is 0.07 a widely acceptable threshold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if ICC < .07 is standard but keep in mind that the population and subject matter of your survey can greatly impact the ICC.  Topics and populations can be more homogeneous than others so it is hard to set a standard acceptable level.  I would recommend focusing instead on outliers in the ICC of interviewers or setting some benchmark based on previous data.

Comment: thank you. I had been thinking that if >0.07 was standard, it wouldn't be so difficult to confirm.  What do you mean by focusing on outliers in the ICC? Do you mean interviewers who are outliers?